# Regular Expression with or without /g (CoffeeScript/JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, regex, coffeescript

Why if I add `/g` to `lineRoute` `parseRoute` function just return only one occurrence?

```
pkt = "Record-Route: <sip:10.1.20.40;lr;r2=on>\r\nRecord-Route: <sip:10.1.20.40:80;transport=ws;r2=on;lr=on>\r\n"

parseRoute = (pkt) ->
        lineRoute = /Route\:/
        route = ""
        for line in pkt.split '\r\n'
            if lineRoute.test line
                tmp = line.split ': '
                route += tmp[1] + ", \r\n"
        return route
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reuse the RegEx object every call to `test` will start from index of the previous match. So in between each call to test you have to reset the this index:

```
lineRoute.lastIndex = 0
```

Your function:

```
parseRoute = (pkt) ->
    lineRoute = /Route\:/
    route = ""
    for line in abc
        lineRoute.lastIndex = 0;
        if lineRoute.test line
            tmp = line.split ': '
            route += tmp[1] + ", \r\n"
    return route
```

This property is only used when the global flag is set `/g`. That explains why it works when you don't use the global flag.

Read more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions (search for `lastIndex`)